# White Screen before SplashScreen for no reason

Tags: flutter, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I am having trouble removing the white screen that appears before my splash screen. I saw many videos and followed their instructions but still, that white screen don't go away. I am a beginner so I don't have much knowledge to solve it, kindly help!

I am using `initState` to show the splash screen. I have also put my splash image inside the drawable folder and this is how my `launch_background.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so my problem was solved when I added my splash in `styles.xml` file:

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```